# SQL error while getting data from table by 'type' column

Tags: sql, database, laravel

I want to group by date in single query but for different data. I have tried this so far :

```
$record_by_date = DB::select("SELECT SUM(amount) as 'amount', 
   cast(date as date) dateAdded  FROM expense_incomes WHERE (CASE WHEN 
   type='Expense' THEN 'Expense' WHEN type='Income' THEN 'Income' END AS Type) 
   GROUP BY cast(date as date)");
```

First is it correct way to do it? I am using CASE 
Second, if it is correct way, I am getting error, how to solve this?

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
> error in your  SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MariaDB server version for  the right syntax to use near 'AS `Type`)
> GROUP BY cast(date as date)' at line 1  (SQL: SELECT SUM(amount) as
> 'amount', cast(date as date) dateAdded FROM  expense_incomes WHERE
> (CASE WHEN type='Expense' THEN 'Expense' WHEN type='Income'  THEN
> 'Income' END AS `Type`) GROUP BY cast(date as date))

Comment: Do you still need an answer for this issue?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Thank you it is solved now

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your WHERE clause, CASE defines Type but it doesn't actually compare it to anything, so its kinda goes like WHERE(1)

Comment: How do I get SUM by type?

Comment: remove `WHERE`, add third resulting column `Type`, and group by two columns, `cast(date as date)` and `Type`, separated by a comma.

Comment: get rid of case statement, try to group it by `type`

Comment: I get two records for 2021--04-04, when there is both expense and income on 4th April

Answer (score 0):

It seems you put your SQL Queries to DB::select();

Try to use DB::raw() for get desired result

```
$record_by_date = DB::raw("SELECT SUM(amount) as 'amount', 
   cast(date as date) dateAdded  FROM expense_incomes WHERE (CASE WHEN 
   type='Expense' THEN 'Expense' WHEN type='Income' THEN 'Income' END AS Type) 
   GROUP BY cast(date as date)"))->get();
```

[Laravel Queries Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-expressions)